# onLoad or onShow event of ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am displaying a tab `Upload` of Image Dialogue box using below code.

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev )
          {
              // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event
              // data.
              var dialogName = ev.data.name;
              var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

              // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
              // interested on (the "Link" dialog).
              if ( dialogName == 'image' )
              {
                dialogDefinition.dialog.resize( 700, 500 );
                // Add a new tab to the "Link" dialog.
                dialogDefinition.addContents({
                    id : 'uploadTab',
                    label : 'upload',
                    elements : [
                      {
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'uploadField',
                        label: 'upload',     
                      }
                    ]
                });
              }
          });
```

[image]

Now I would like to catch `onLoad` event of `Tab`.

How can I do that ?